# I'm getting this problem while running the selenium click event

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation

Expected condition failed: waiting for element to no longer be visible: By.className: RegisterBtn (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: Hi. Can you share some code for what you are trying to achieve. And on what page you are trying to find the element on. It is hard for us to help you without any information.

Comment: Hi Kiksen, Thanks,It's fixed. I Increase the Wait time using Thread.Sleep();